# Hamming distance function for bits is an injective or surjective function?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

### Let's say we have

d: T8 x T8 -> {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}
$$d(a,b) = \sum_{i=1}^8 ai \oplus bi $$

Where a1 is the bit a that is at position i and bi and the bit b that is in position i.

### Would this be an injective or surjective function?

If I understand correctly it is an injective function, but have trouble exactly explaining why.

Thanks.

Comment: It should be $a_i\oplus b_i$, not $a1 \oplus b1$

Comment: What are you considering as the domain and codomain of the function $d$?

Answer (score 0):

To be injective you would have to have the distance be unique for each pair of bit strings.  As there are only $9$ possible distances and many more pairs of bit strings, there must be multiple pairs that have the same distance.  It should not be hard to find a specific example.

Comment: The domain would be T8 x T8

Comment: The domain is not so important for injectivity.  It is mostly the codomain.  Do more than one item in the domain go to one item in the codomain?